# Why do Linux bridges show two MAC address entries for local interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

Why do Linux bridges show two MAC address entries for local interfaces?

```
brctl showmacs bridge1  
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer  
  1 0c:b4:7a:f5:36:b6   no        23.90   
  1 0c:b4:7a:f5:37:3b   no        19.58  
  1 0c:a4:7a:f9:d7:04   yes        0.00  
  1 0c:a4:7a:f9:d7:04   yes        0.00  
 10 fe:c4:00:ab:d5:18   yes        0.00   
 10 fe:c4:00:ab:d5:18   yes        0.00
```

Answer (score 5):

This is similar in my Debian 9:

```
# brctl showmacs br0
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer
  2     00:08:ca:42:2c:02       yes                0.00
  2     00:08:ca:42:2c:02       yes                0.00
  1     00:30:18:a6:cb:21       yes                0.00
  1     00:30:18:a6:cb:21       yes                0.00
```

These entries are from FDB (Forwarding Database). There is another tool that can show it:

```
# bridge fdb show | grep 'master br0'
00:30:18:a6:cb:21 dev eth1 vlan 1 master br0 permanent
00:30:18:a6:cb:21 dev eth1 master br0 permanent
00:08:ca:42:2c:02 dev wlan0 master br0 permanent
00:08:ca:42:2c:02 dev wlan0 vlan 1 master br0 permanent
```

Two entries with the same MAC address look identical in the output of `brctl` but `bridge` shows they are different. For each pair there's one with `vlan 1` and one without.

`vlan 1` refers to [virtual LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN) (VLAN) with identifier 1. It indicates there is a VLAN filter entry for this particular identifier.

> A basic switch that is not configured for VLANs has VLAN functionality disabled or permanently enabled with a default VLAN that contains all ports on the device as members. The default VLAN typically uses VLAN identifier 1.

I have never explicitly configured this `vlan 1` in my Debian; it's there by default. I tried to investigate where it comes from and found [this discussion](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5716). The issue there is not related to your question, still it shows that `vlan 1` is nothing strange in VLAN-aware bridge in Linux.

To confirm VLANs are relevant to what you asked, I did this:

```
# bridge vlan show dev eth1
port    vlan ids
eth1     1 PVID Egress Untagged

# bridge vlan add vid 123 dev eth1
#
# bridge vlan show dev eth1
port    vlan ids
eth1     1 PVID Egress Untagged
         123

# bridge fdb show | grep 'master br0'
00:30:18:a6:cb:21 dev eth1 vlan 123 master br0 permanent
00:30:18:a6:cb:21 dev eth1 vlan 1 master br0 permanent
00:30:18:a6:cb:21 dev eth1 master br0 permanent
00:08:ca:42:2c:02 dev wlan0 master br0 permanent
00:08:ca:42:2c:02 dev wlan0 vlan 1 master br0 permanent
#
# brctl showmacs br0
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer
  2     00:08:ca:42:2c:02       yes                0.00
  2     00:08:ca:42:2c:02       yes                0.00
  1     00:30:18:a6:cb:21       yes                0.00
  1     00:30:18:a6:cb:21       yes                0.00
  1     00:30:18:a6:cb:21       yes                0.00
#
# bridge vlan del vid 123 dev eth1
#
# sudo brctl showmacs br0
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer
  2     00:08:ca:42:2c:02       yes                0.00
  2     00:08:ca:42:2c:02       yes                0.00
  1     00:30:18:a6:cb:21       yes                0.00
  1     00:30:18:a6:cb:21       yes                0.00
```

As you can see, after adding VLAN filter with identifier `123` (arbitrary number, an example) to my `eth1`, `brctl showmacs` lists its MAC address *three* times. `123` deleted – and we're back to two.

---

Summary:

- Your bridge is aware of VLANs.
- Each bridged local interface has one VLAN filter entry added (`vlan X`, most likely `vlan 1`).
- In effect FDB contains two entries per such interface: one entry with `vlan X` and one without.
- `brctl showmacs` shows these entries but omits information about VLANs, therefore there are lines that look identical.
- `bridge fdb show` doesn't omit information about VLANs, it will show you the actual entries are different.